# RStoolbox package failing to install on R version 4.1.2

Tags: r, rtools

I want to do supervised classification using the code below
`t1972_sup<- superclass(t1972, model = "rf", train1972, responseCol = "id", trainPartition = 0.7)`
However, I need to install RStoobox `install.packages("RStoolbox")` for my random forest. I cant seem to win with this code and I have tried this [writeup here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html) but no win. I have since installed Rtools for R from version 4.0.0 to 4.1.3. I followed through the process `Sys.which("make")`and getting this `> Sys.which("make") make  "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"` .

When I try again to install RStoolbox, I get this error
`> install.packages("RStoolbox")
Installing package into ‘D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘RStoolbox’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
[https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages%60)

Could I be missing something? Please help

I have checked the link https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html for guiding required RTools before installing RStoolbox on windows.

Comment: It looks like the RStoolbox package was [archived](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStoolbox/index.html).  You could try downloading the [most recent source](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RStoolbox/RStoolbox_0.3.0.tar.gz) and installing from the local package.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, I have downloaded the most recent source you provided and did run the code `install.packages("C:\Users\kondw\Desktop\TimeSeries_Kalomo\RStoolbox", 
                 repos = NULL, 
                 type = "source")`. I am getting the error: `> install.packages("C:\Users\kondw\Desktop\TimeSeries_Kalomo\RStoolbox", 
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
>                  repos = NULL, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "                 repos = NULL,"
>                  type = "source")
Error: unexpected ')' in "                 type = "source")"`

Comment: The problem is that on windows, you need to separate folders on the path with either `\\` or `/` - either will work.  For example, you could use: `install.packages("C:\\Users\\kondw\\Desktop\\TimeSeries_Kalomo\\RStoolbox",repos = NULL, type = "source")`, but you may need to point it to the `.tar.gz` archive.

Comment: Running `install.packages("C:\\Users\\kondw\\Desktop\\TimeSeries_Kalomo\\RStoolbox",repos = NULL, type = "source")` and got error  ` 
Installing package into ‘D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) ERROR: dependencies 'caret', 'XML', 'reshape2', 'exactextractr', 'doParallel', 'foreach', 'RcppArmadillo' are not available for package 'RStoolbox'
* removing 'D:/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RStoolbox'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/kondw/Desktop/TimeSeries_Kalomo/RStoolbox’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: It's telling you that you need to install all those dependencies first.  Since you've set `repos=NULL` (which is the right thing to do here), the function can't find all the other dependencies.  Try this first: `install.packages(c( 'caret', 'XML', 'reshape2', 'exactextractr', 'doParallel', 'foreach', 'RcppArmadillo'))`

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, trying ` install.packages(c( 'caret', 'XML', 'reshape2', 'exactextractr', 'doParallel', 'foreach', 'RcppArmadillo'))
`  fails with error   ` install.packages(c( 'caret', 'XML', 'reshape2', 'exactextractr', 'doParallel', 'foreach', 'RcppArmadillo')) `

Comment: It is showing a failure to some directory : `Versions of these packages for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1:
  cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\kondw\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkPKThw\file11d05a8d3996', reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: Can you try installing each one of those packages independently to see if it is just one that fails?

Comment: Trying these independently too failed.                                          
`install.packages("caret")
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("reshape2")
install.packages('doParallel')
install.packages("RcppArmadillo")`                                                                             `Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\kondw\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkPKThw\file11d03d7650ea', reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: Have you tried restarting R and trying again? Aside from that, I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: The installation for dependencies (caret, XML, ...) later worked after several restarts. Weirdly with same code. However, installing RStoolbox `install.packages("RStoolbox")` failed giving an error ` installation of package ‘C:/Users/kondw/Desktop/TimeSeries_Kalomo/RStoolbox’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Have you tried installing the package from GitHub?  `devtools::install_github("bleutner/RStoolbox")`

Comment: I just tried that and got : ` devtools::install_github("bleutner/RStoolbox")`
`Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required'

Comment: Restart R and reinstall the  rlang package. Depending on the dependencies for rlang 1.0.6, you may need another strategy, like an older commit on GitHub or upgrading R.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, thanks a lot for the guide and hints to resolving this. It finally worked using `install.packages("devtools")` , `library(devtools)`, and then running a specific version of RStoolbox (in this case 0.2.6). I used the code `devtools::install_version('RStoolbox', '0.2.6')`.